# add string in file with sed doesn't works

Tags: sed

I have an xml and i would like to add some text between a string. The string is like:

```
.....
    <JOB ID="122" ... MEM="C:\Program Files" CONF="YES" .....>
.....
```

I'm trying to add string after mem field with these:

```
 sed "s/.*MEM=\"\(.*\)\".*/MEM=\"\1\" TEST_TO_INSERT=\"INSERT\".*/g" file
```

I would like to have:

```
.....
    <JOB ID="122" ... MEM="C:\Program Files" TEST_TO_INSERT="INSERT" CONF="YES" .....>
.....
```

And it doesn't works, add test at the end of the line. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: sorry I want to have: <JOB ID="122" ... MEM="C:\Program Files" TEST_TO_INSERT="INSERT" CONF="YES" .....>

Comment: `sed -e 's/MEM="[^"]*"/& TEST_TO_INSERT="INSERT"/' file` might get you closer.   You probably do not need g option on the substitution, and you do not need .* in the replacement unless you want a literal .* there.   Finally, you can use `&` in the replacement to mean the entire match.

Comment: As a starting point - always use single quotes (`'`) around scripts or strings in shell unless you NEED double quotes (`"`), which you don't. So start with `sed 's/.*MEM="\(.*\)".*/MEM="\1" TEST_TO_INSERT="INSERT".*/g' file` instead of `sed "s/.*MEM=\"\(.*\)\".*/MEM=\"\1\" TEST_TO_INSERT=\"INSERT\".*/g" file` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser to parse XML data. [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is one.

Given `file.xml` as

```xml
<root>
<JOB ID="122" attr2="value2" MEM="C:\Program Files" CONF="YES" attr5="value5">
</JOB>
</root>
```

Then

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -O -i '//JOB[@MEM]' -t attr -n TEST_TO_INSERT -v 'INSERT' file.xml
```

will add then attribute to JOB nodes that have a MEM attribute. Output:

```xml
<root>
  <JOB ID="122" attr2="value2" MEM="C:\Program Files" CONF="YES" attr5="value5" TEST_TO_INSERT="INSERT">
</JOB>
</root>
```

Note that the order of attributes is not significant.

---

This only prints the modified XML. To save it back to the file, use:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed --inplace ... file.xml
```